# Symfony2 form widget container attributes

Tags: forms, symfony, attributes, widget

I need set a class for widget container, but have no idea how Symfony passes attributes to "widget_container_attributes" block

Widget container template:

```
{% block form_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {{ block('field_rows') }}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget %}
```

Example result:

```
<div class="MY-CLASS">
    <label class="required" for="page_title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" value="Next subpage" maxlength="500" required="required" name="page[title]" id="page_title">
</div>
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    {% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

    {% block field_rows %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_row(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
    {% endblock field_rows %}

    {% block field_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="myclass">
          {{ form_label(form, label|trans) }}
          {{ form_widget(form) }}
          {{ form_errors(form) }}                            
       </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
    {% endblock field_row %}
```

Comment: The point is not setting it static, but dynamically from the form code

Comment: Ok, I extended field type to custom option used in field_row block. Thanks for pointing out proper block to extend.